# copying an element from list<string>mylist to string mystr

Tags: c++, arrays, string, list

```
list<string> mylist;
mylist.push_back("random stuff");
list<string>::iterator it;
it=mylist.begin();
string mystr;
//and this doesn't work:
mystr=*it;
```

Let's say I have a `list<string> mylist` and it has 3 items. Since I can't work on the characters of each element I must copy what item I want to a simple string or a char buffer. But I can't find a way at all, I've tried with pointers to arrays as well.
So is there a way to copy those items out of the list ?

Edit:
Yeah sorry , revisited my code , the project that is , and found the error to be somewere else, i was copying from listmylist to a string mystr, with the help of an iterator, and i was using a for loop that had the condition to stop when it encountered the character '\0' put when i was copying it, it didn't copy the '\0' in my string so in the end i had to put it manually so the function would not work outside the string
Good code:

```
    string temp;
    list<string>::iterator it;
    it=mylist.begin();//let's say myslist has "random stuff"
    temp=*it;//this does not copy the '\0'
    temp+='\0';//so i add it myself 
    for(int n(0);temp[n]!='\0';n++)//now the for loop stops properly
        cout<<temp[n];
```

Comment: what do you want to do? You _think_ you need to 'copy to a simple string' (what is that) but I don't think it's true. What do you _really_ want to do? (_by the way, the code shown should work nicely: see http://ideone.com/Z3Yat_)

Comment: This question is very poorly constructed and presented. Tidy it up, and perhaps you should state your goals rather than what you believe the first step should be.

Comment: `mystring = *it` oughts to work, there has to be something else wrong. Is that your real code?

Comment: "since i cant work on the characters of each element": why are you saying that? You can simply use the iterators of `std::string`.

Comment: `std::string mystr = mylist.front()`?

Comment: The code you've posted works just fine. http://www.ideone.com/pVH0T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works great and outputs the correct result.  Also, you can work with characters of each element like this:

```
for (list<string>::iterator iter = mylist.begin(); iter != mylist.end(); ++iter)
{
    char c = (*iter)[0];  //this is the first character.
}
```

You can cycle through the string with an iterator too even, strings have them as well :) Though strings support random-access-iterators, so you can just access them as arrays like a c-string as I showed in the for loop.

Comment: complementary answers :) (even when guessing the question...)

Comment: Yeah sorry , revisited my code , the project that is , and found the error to be somewere else, i was copying from list<string>mylist to a string mystr, with the help of an iterator, and i was using a for loop that had the condition to stop when it encountered the character '\0' put when i was copying it, it didn't copy the '\0' in my string so in  the end i had to put it manually so the function would not work outside the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want characters from the string:

```
for (std::string::iterator it=mystr.begin(); it!=mystr.end(); it++)
{
     char ch = *it;
     // do something with the character?
}
```

If you want to pass the string as a C (zero-terminated) string, use

```
mystr.c_str()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for

```
list<string> mylist;
mylist.push_back("random stuff");
list<string>::iterator it = it=mylist.begin();
string& mystr = *it; // Note the &
```

The type `string&` is a reference to a string. It introduces a new name for the first element of the list. Well, at least what's currently the first element. You could of course do `mylist_push_front("Hi There");` and `mystr` would still be "random stuff". But if you now say `mystr = "Not so random stuff";`, you will change the string inside the list.

Note that this is *explicitly* not a copy.

Small warning: `mystr` doesn't magically keep the string alive. If you remove the underlying string from the list, you must stop using `mystr` as well.